# React: Interact with fabric.js canvas instance from another component

Tags: reactjs, meteor, fabricjs

I am trying to create a UI to interact with a fabricjs canvas. On the left will be a component that displays a library of items that can be added to the canvas. In the middle will be the fabricjs canvas, and on the right will be a component that lists all the added items that are on the canvas (similar to photoshops layers panel).

I want to know how I can have an onClick event within the component on the left (ItemsList.js), access the fabricjs canvas instance that is declared in it's parent component.

This is the main component...

**MainComponent.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';

import ItemsList from './ItemsList.js';
import LayersPanel from './LayersPanel.js';

import {fabric} from 'fabric';

class Designer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      canvasWidth: ''
    };
  }

  updateCanvasDimensions() {
    this.setState({
      canvasWidth: this.refs.canvas_wrapper.offsetWidth
    });
    canvas.setHeight(this.state.canvasWidth);
    canvas.setWidth(this.state.canvasWidth);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
      width: this.refs.canvas_wrapper.offsetWidth,
      height: this.refs.canvas_wrapper.offsetWidth
    });
    this.updateCanvasDimensions(canvas);
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.updateCanvasDimensions.bind(this));
    canvas.renderAll();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this.updateCanvasDimensions.bind(this));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>

          <div>
            <ItemsList />
          </div>

          <div className="canvas-wrapper" ref="canvas_wrapper">
            <canvas ref="c" id = "c"></canvas>
          </div>

          <div>
            <LayersPanel />
          </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default createContainer(({ params }) => {

  return {
  };

}, Designer);
```

**Somewhere within ItemsList.js, for each item on the list, there is a button to add the item's image to the canvas.**

```
...
<Button onClick={() => {

    //Need to get the canvas instance here so 
    //that I can add this particular item's image to the canvas like this...

    canvas.add(rowData.image);

}}>Add Item</Button>
...
```

After this button is clicked for a particular item in the ItemsList component, I want the clicked item's image to be added to the canvas that is declared in a components up the tree. For example...

```
<MainComponent> <-- This is where I declare the fabric canvas.
  <ItemsList>
     <Item/>  <-- This is where the button is clicked.
  </ItemsList>
</MainComponent>
```

How can I access the canvas instance from within `<Item/>`?

In case it's relevant to the answer, at the same time, I also need the component on the right (`<LayersPanel/>`) to display what is added to the canvas.

Thanks

Answer (score -3):

I have managed to do this with the following...

Create the canvas...

```
<canvas ref="c" id = "c"></canvas>
```

Pick it up from anywhere (as long as it has loaded of course)...

```
 canvas = document.getElementById("c").fabric;
```